# My cookie disappears in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

I'm working on an issue that a cookie disappears after refreshing the page. I'm totally new to this page and doesn't know any code in either client/server side, so I decide to trace the http by fiddler.

This is a session cookie which has no expire date assigned, neither does the domain path. I checked all http request during the refreshing, found nothing related to "Set-Cookie" in the response header, but the cookie just disappeared.

This issue happened in IE, FF, Chrome. I don't think it's a browser related issue.

As I don't own the server side code, I can't search the code by the cookie name. Any idea what can possible be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking your page source and JS file, cookie could potentially be deleted by Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply:) I did check my page and didn't see anything related to the cookie. I could try to check all the JavaScript files, it just takes a while to download all of them, quite a lot there....

Comment: Since you use fiddler you can try to search the cookie name in all requests in fiddler

Comment: That's it! I just sorted it out using exactly the same way you said. Thx a lot!